# How to setup a Django-site where users have different permissions for different projects

Tags: django, database, structure

Kind stacky! Hopefully you can help me out.

I'm trying to workout a web-application on which I can easily develop django-apps and distribute them to the users. On the web-application users should be able to create different projects and invite other users. In the project environment all of the django-apps should be accessible. The data of the apps should be project-depended and only be accessible and editable when you are part of the project.

I am struggling working out the right structures so that the data is only accessible and editable if you are part of a project.

To summarize:

- I have 1 Django Project
- I have multiple apps, and will be adding more later on.
- Users are able to start a project and invite users.
- Within the project all apps are available, but only the project-specific data is vissible and edditable.
- If a user has no access, they are not able to see the project data.

Questions that are spooking through my head are: How do I need to setup my model? How do I go about setting up permissions? How do I make sure they can not access project data to which they don't have permissions.

**I understand there is not one true solution, but I am looking for recommendations on best practices or working examples. I just don't know how to start.**

I already searched the internet extensively but I can't find anything that resembles what I want to do.

My line of thought currently is to create a project class in models.py
In models.py I create a project class which has a relation with the users class. Then I design my urls so that they look like this: www.example.com/project//app1/certainpage

## Update:

I am pursuing my initial line of thought. It seems to be working. I'm just not sure if it's the 'proper' way. What I did so far:

- I created a projects app in which I created a project model.
- I created a many to many relation between the project model and users.
- I created a relation between all other models and the project model, with foreignkey.
- I reconstructed all my urls so that they look like this: www.example.com/project//app/...
- I created a decorator which combines the login_required decorator and a decorator I constructed myself, which checks if the user has a relation with the project and will redirect if not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you'll have:

- 1 Django project
- Multiple Django apps (representing real-life projects)
- Multiple users that can have access (or no access) to individual apps

Users should also be able to create apps for projects, and add other users. Users can only see a project content if they have the appropriate permissions.

---

I think one viable approach would be to work with Django's build-in Users and Groups. Look into Django's docs on [Permissions and Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

It might get tricky when figuring out the best permissions to allow users to create new apps/projects but *not* give them full access as an administrator. How exactly that has to look like heavily depends on your actual use case.

But it is possible to give users certain permissions in the admin portal, but disallow other admin-related actions.

I'd suggest to try going down that road, since Django's in-built User, Group, and Permission structure is extensive, and integrates by design with the pre-built admin dashboard.

---

You might find helpful sections in the following resources:

- [User Authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/)
- [MDN's Django example app (Authentication section)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication)
- [Implement Multiple User Types](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)